# Strange "r-wtfaq" tag

Tags: discussion, tags, meta-tags

In my review queue, my attention was attracted by this [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r-wtfaq/info) proposed wiki, quote:

> R related questions which have no meaning whatsoever (troll/spam/very
>   vogue/no minimal understanding in R) tagged with this tag in order to
>   drive attention from other R users and bring these questions to
>   immediate closing/deletion.

Which was proposed, and that's unexpected part, by pretty high-rep user. He seems to be the only one who created, subscribed to this tag, and tagging questions with it by editing.

Is it plain misuse and abuse of a tag system? I would certainly think so if only this user didn't have this much rep, meaning he must be pretty experienced with SO. So maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Good catch, Petr. Have no idea what's up with this guy...

Comment: ^ not sure if trolling or serious, aren't you the same guy we are talking about in this question.

Comment: @wardha-Web He's neither trolling nor serious.

Comment: ('very vogue' was an unintentionally hilarious typo)

Comment: Anyway seems this tag never got anywhere, back in 2014/5

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yes, it is. If you want to point out a bad question, you downvote and/or vote to close it. Not tag it. (A long time ago, we used to have people going around tagging questions with [plzsendtehcodez](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plzsendtehcodez). You can imagine how that one went down.)

I've rejected the tag wiki, reversed the edits and spoken to the user responsible. Needless to say, any robo-reviewers that might have passed by were dealt with as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying :) I guess someone from mods should notify user about his actions being inappropriate.

Comment: @Petr Abdulin: Yeah, rest assured we will.

Comment: That tag is absolutely gorgeous, I would love to use it everyday!!

Comment: Hmm.  What exactly is wrong with this behaviour?  What negative consequence does it have beyond being slightly offensive to the asker?

Comment: @tmyklebu: It's simply not appropriate to use tags for anything other than to categorize a question by its subject matter. Not for saying a question is bad, off-topic, unclear, etc. You use votes, not tags, to deal with such questions.

Comment: @BoltClock: Right.  I guess I didn't ask my question properly.  Why would it be bad if this behaviour were permitted?  That is, why would it be bad if tags were repurposed to categorise questions both according to subject matter and according to the question's nature?  I can see why *inherently demeaning* tags like plzsendtehcodez and r-wtfaq are officially frowned upon, but why not have tags for "debug my code" questions and "why was this designed that way" questions and "implementation" questions?  Too error-prone to be useful?  Something else?

Comment: @tmyklebu: These are called meta tags. There was a [blog post](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags) about this a while back. Simply put, one of the reasons these tags are not useful is because they can't stand alone as the only tag on a question. The blog post explains it better. (Although I would *love* a "why was this designed that way" tag, I think that can adequately be expressed in the title.)

Comment: @BoltClock: OK, cool.

Comment: I'd say that not only is the tagging inappropriate, but even the intended purpose of telling other people to vote a certain way about a question is inappropriate.